# Why std::(i)ostream treat signed / unsigned char as a text and not an integer?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

This code doesn't do what it's supposed to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    uint8_t small_integer;
    std::cin >> small_integer;
    std::cout << small_integer;
}
```

The reason is simple: `uint8_t` is a typedef for `unsigned char` and streams treat this type as a text:
*Visual C++ 2015 implementation*

```
template<class _Traits> inline
    basic_istream<char, _Traits>& operator>>(
        basic_istream<char, _Traits>& _Istr, unsigned char& _Ch)
    {    // extract an unsigned char
    return (_Istr >> (char&)_Ch);
    }
```

And a similar code with cast to `char` for `operator <<`.

My questions:

1. Is this behavior (streaming operators treating signed / unsigned char as character type and not an integer) required by the standard?
   If it is then:

   2. What is the rationale behind such counterintuitive semantics?
   3. Should this be considered a defect, were there proposals to change this semantics?

I should probably add a little explanation why I consider it counterintuitive. 
Although the type name contains the word char, the `signed` or `unsigned` part specify particular integer semantic and those types are generally used as byte sized integers. Even the standard defines `int8_t` / `uint8_t` through them.

**UPD:** The question is about behavior of streaming operator overloads for `unsigned char` and `signed char`.

Comment: It is annoying. I've used my own to_string function that treats (u)int8_t as integers while treating char as a character. I added separate specializations for uint8_t, int8_t, and char since I'm assuming it's perfectly valid for those not to be three distinct types.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but [`std::byte`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0257r0.pdf) has been proposed to overcome this problem.

Comment: @Praetorian, while this is indeed an interesting proposal, it addresses an absolutely different issue.

Comment: @Matt I would have assumed that the compiler can't distinguish between `int8_t` and `char` as types in an argument list. Does your `to_string` actually work the way you intend?

Comment: It can't work if either `int8_t` or `uint8_t` is a typedef for `char`, but it can work if they are typedefs for `signed char` and `unsigned char`.

Comment: "Is *this* behavior" - could you clarify?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, I added a clarification, it was a badly worded phrase.

Answer (score 3):

The standard (n3797) says the following:

> *27.7.2.2.3 basic_istream::operator>>*

```
template<class charT, class traits> 
basic_istream<charT,traits>& operator>>(basic_istream<charT,traits>& in, charT& c);

template<class traits> 
basic_istream<char,traits>& operator>>(basic_istream<char,traits>& in, unsigned char& c);

template<class traits> 
basic_istream<char,traits>& operator>>(basic_istream<char,traits>& in, signed char& c);
```

> 12 Eﬀects: Behaves like a formatted input member (as described in 27.7.2.2.1) of in. After a sentry object is constructed **a character is extracted** from in, if one is available, and stored in c. Otherwise, the function calls in.setstate(failbit).
>
> *27.7.3.6.4 Character inserter function templates*

```
// specialization 
template<class traits> 
basic_ostream<char,traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<char,traits>& out, char c); 

// signed and unsigned 
template<class traits> 
basic_ostream<char,traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<char,traits>& out, signed char c); 

template<class traits> 
basic_ostream<char,traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<char,traits>& out, unsigned char c);
```

> 1 Eﬀects: Behaves as a formatted output function ( 27.7.3.6.1) of out. Constructs a character sequence seq. If c has type char and the character type of the stream is not char, then **seq consists of out.widen(c); otherwise seq consists of c**. Determines padding for seq as described in 27.7.3.6.1. Inserts seq into out. Calls os.width(0).

So the answer to the first question: yes, the standard requires that `operator >>` and `operator <<` behave exactly the same for `char`, `unsigned char` and `signed char`, that is they read / write a single character, not an integer. Unfortunately, standard doesn't explain why. I hope someone will shed light on 2 and 3.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Is this behavior required by the standard? If it is then:

You already answered this. Yes, the standard defines how iostreams should handle signed and unsigned char.

> 2. What is the rationale behind such counterintuitive semantics?

Because `signed char` and `unsigned char` are *character types*, so they are always treated as characters by the iostreams classes.

The clue is in the name: `signed char` is a signed character type. `unsigned char` is an unsigned character type.  The other integral types have `int` in their name (even if it's sometimes optional, e.g. `short` and `long unsigned` are identical to `short int` and `long unsigned int` respectively).

The standard doesn't need to say *why* this is true, because it's not a design document or a rationale for the history of C and C++, it's a specification.

If you want a type that behaves like an integer with only 8 bits then you'll need to create your own (e.g. using an enumeration type or a struct that holds a value) and define the relevant operator overloads.

> 3. Should this be considered a defect, were there proposals to change this semantics?

No, I don't think so. They have always been character types and it would break too much code to change that.