# how to initialize an unsigned integer uint8_t

Tags: c++

How to use uint8_t and to initialize a variable

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    uint8_t a = 6;
    cout << a;
    return 1;
}
```

It is printing some symbol

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why std::(i)ostream treat signed / unsigned char as a text and not an integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36843616/why-stdiostream-treat-signed-unsigned-char-as-a-text-and-not-an-integer)

Comment: uint8_t is just an unsigned char, so it is printed as char, `static_cast` it to uint16_t when printing if you want to see a number istead of symbol

Answer (score 3):

C++ treats `uint8_t` as `char` - because that's pretty much what it is.

If you pass a `char` to `cout`, it'll print as a `char`, which, with a value of 6, is the ACK symbol (which would probably display strangely, depending on your terminal settings).

If you want it to be printed as a number, casting it to an `unsigned` in `cout` should do the trick:

```
cout << (unsigned)a;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the variable **a** in order to print that as a number and not an ascii symbol

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstdint>

 int main()
{
    uint8_t a = 6;
    std::cout << "a: " << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "a casted to char(is the same type actually): " << char(a) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "a casted to int: " << int(a) << std::endl;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use good old type-unsafe `printf`.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    std::uint8_t a = 6;
    std::printf("%d\n", a);
}
```